# TypeORM update doesn't work for relationship but save does

Tags: nestjs, repository, typeorm

I'm trying to update one record and its relation associated but having a hard time doing so.

I tried with the save method this way and it works:

```
await this.orderRepository.save(
    {
        ...orderRecord,
        orderStatus: mappedOrderStatus,
        shipments: [...orderRecord.shipments, shipment], // [..., ..., ...]
    },
);
```

orderRecord:

```
Order {
  id: 1,
  createdAt: 2023-01-23T15:56:25.733Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-01-23T15:56:25.733Z,
  orderNumber: 174,
  shipments: [
    Shipment {
      id: 1,
      createdAt: 2023-01-23T15:56:25.433Z,
      updatedAt: 2023-01-23T15:56:25.433Z,
      orders: [Array]
    }
  ]
}
```

However If I try to do the same thing but using update method, it gives me the following error: `Cannot query across many-to-many for property shipments`

```
await this.orderRepository.update(orderRecord.id, {
    orderStatus: mappedOrderStatus,
    shipments: [...orderRecord.shipments, asd],
});
```

order.entity.ts

```
@ManyToMany(() => Shipment,
    (shipment) => shipment.orders)
shipments: Shipment[]
```

shipment.entity.ts

```
@ManyToMany(() => Order,
    (order) => order.shipments,
    { cascade: true }
)
@JoinTable()
orders: Order[]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead with `save` method, it seems like inserting relational data in *many-to-many* case is not implemented for `update` yet.

This might not be related to the driver. [the issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2821) is still open in github.